# tengo el siguiente arrreglo y lo quiero separar por el delimitador "-"

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [0] => 13929805-313
    [1] => 13929807-313
)
```

Estoy aprendiendo y me gustaría separarlo de la siguiente manera:

> 13929805 13929807 313 313

Espero me puedan apoyar.

Gracias

Comment: En el segundo enlace hay un ejemplo que muestra cómo usar `explode` dentro de un `foreach`.